# Calculate integral with $\sin and cos

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integrate $\int_0^x\frac{\cos x}{(a+b\cos x+c\sin x)}\,dx$

I have simplified my original integral to this form, but I don't know how to move forward. Any suggestions?

Comment: from $x=0$ to $x=?$ .  also would you be able to show your work on how you simplified the original to this form.

Comment: x itself I mean

Comment: Try this here https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstraß-Substitution

Comment: Thanks a lot for oyu